# problem with deleting list item in prolog

Tags: list, dynamic, prolog, element

my code in prolog

```
:- dynamic kitchenfurniture/1.

kitchenfurniture([furniture(fridge,1), furniture(table,2), furniture(chair,1)]).

writel([H|T]) :- write(H), nl, writel(T).

whatkitchenfurniture :- kitchenfurniture(X), writel(X).

addkitchenfurniture(X) :- kitchenfurniture(Y), append(Y, [X], Z), retract(kitchenfurniture(Y)), assert(kitchenfurniture(Z)).

deletekitchenfurniture(X) :- kitchenfurniture(Y), delete(X, Y, Z),  retract(kitchenfurniture(Y)), assert(kitchenfurniture(Z)).
```

when I enter the code in the console

[image]

it does not remove the item from the list

problem wth line code deletekitchenfurniture(furniture(fridge,1)).

Comment: It would probably be better if you included console output as a code snipped if possible. The `stackoverflow` policy discourages using images unless it's necessary, e.g. to show something that cannot be described (or is extremely hard to describe)  otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand what exactly you type into the console; why don't you show it?

It is probable that this is wrong:

```
?- deleteaddkitchenfurniture('furniture(fridge,1)').
```

The correct way to do it might be:

```
?- deleteaddkitchenfurniture(furniture(fridge,1)).
```

No single quotes there. If you put it in single quotes, it becomes an atom with some parentheses embedded in it. If you don't quote, it is a compound term, as in the original list you have in here:

```
kitchenfurniture([furniture(fridge,1), furniture(table,2), furniture(chair,1)]).
```

Comment: I did as you wrote but there is still a problem
below I am pasting again two code options and the result from the console

Comment: @user7418450 please remove those answers and add the necessary detail to the question.

Comment: in the two answers above I gave two types of code that I tested and the result from the console
none of these codes were able to remove the item from the list